# Radius of convergence of power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin n!}{n!}} {x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

The power series 
$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin n!}{n!}} {x^n}$  has radius of convergence $R$, then

1. $R\geq1$
2. $R\geq e$
3. $R\geq2e$
4. All are correct

I wanted to know how will get the answer in the form of $e$.

Comment: Since the series without sine has infinite radius of convergence (it's $e^x-1$), and sine is bounded...

Comment: can we get the answer after solving it?

Comment: I modified the title to make it reflect what the OP wanted to say (even though I personally find the notion that this power series would be similar to $\exp(n!)$ or $\exp(\sin n!)$, both depending on $n$, rather dubious).

Answer (score 1):

Expanded comment.

You can prove your series converges for any $x$, by writing the rest:

$$\left|\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n!}{n!}x^n\right| \leq \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\sin n!}{n!}x^n\right| \leq \sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{x^n}{n!}\right|$$

And the last is the rest of the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{|x|^n}{n!}$, which has infinite radius of convergence, as it's the series of $\exp |x|$, whose radius you should know (otherwise, prove it by the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)). So the rest converges to $0$ as $m\rightarrow\infty$. Hence Your series converges for any $x$, and it has also infinite radius of convergence.

Comment: radius is infinity then all the answer are correct? that means option $4$

Comment: @nisha Yes, they are all correct.

Comment: but how?? $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is $e^x$ ..i dint get it properly..

Comment: if in any question raius of convergence is infinity can it take any value?

Comment: @nisha If the **radius** is infinity, then the series converges for any (real or complex) value of the **variable** ($x$ here). But the radius has only one value, and it's greater than any real number (as it's infinity).

Comment: ohk..will it be greater than zero also?and if we say real number it means we take both positive and negative number??

Comment: @nisha The [radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of a power series is either a positive (or zero) number, either $+\infty$. If it's $+\infty$, it's of course greater than any positive, zero, or negative number.

Comment: ohk..thankyou..